# php named constants not loaded if certain case

Tags: php, constants

I have a very strange Issue with a class method:

If I call it with

`$allegato->delete("tutti")`   **(CASE 1)**

I cannot access my named constant... but if I call the same method

`$allegato->delete($fileDaEliminare)`    **(CASE 2)**

everything works as expected.

This is the complete code of class method:

```
    function delete($fileDaEliminare = null) {

    if ($fileDaEliminare == "tutti") {
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE idIncarico = :idIncarico";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':idIncarico', $this->idIncarico);
        $stmt->execute();

        *** CASE 1 : ERROR ***
        $percorso = APPROOT . DS . UPLOADFOLDER . DS . $this->idIncarico . "*";
        $this->fileSystem->eliminaCartella($percorso);

    } else {
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE fileName = :fileName and idIncarico = :idIncarico";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':fileName', $fileDaEliminare);
        $stmt->bindParam(':idIncarico', $this->idIncarico);
        $stmt->execute();

        *** CASE 2 : OK ***
        $percorso = APPROOT . DS . UPLOADFOLDER . DS . $this->idIncarico;
        $nomeFile = $fileDaEliminare;
        $this->fileSystem->eliminaFile($percorso . DS . $nomeFile);

        // elimina cartella se vuota
        if ($this->fileSystem->cartellaVuota($percorso)) {
            $this->fileSystem->eliminaCartella($percorso);
        }
    }
}
```

Dumping defined constant in both cases with `get_defined_constants`, the `[user]` section is indeed missing for case 2...

config.php

```
define('TIMEZONE', 'Europe/Rome');
define('UPLOADFOLDER', "uploads");
define('PERIZIEFOLDER', "perizieGenerate");
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('APPROOT', realpath(__DIR__ . '/..'));
```

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in the original code? Maybe the constant isn't defined yet?

Comment: *No lo so*. You'll need to show us a bit more code, and as to where you've defined your constants.

Comment: If you're using "tutti" as opposed to "Tutti", those are 2 different animals. Your question is impossible to answer in its present state, as you have all the pieces for the puzzles, we dont. Walking away... *buon fortunato*.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I'm not using "Tutti" but just "tutti"... as my code states ... and yes about the puzzle.. but It's a BIG puzzle and I will take my time to explain better. And anyway _Good Luck_ is _Buona Fortuna_ ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example based of your obscure code sample, don't know will it solve your particular problem since you didn't provide more info, but here goes:

```
<?php

// prepare test vars and constants
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('UPLOADFOLDER', 'UPLOADFOLDERconstant');
define('APPROOT', '/var/www/approotDir');

class MyClass{

    var $idIncarico = 999;

    function delete($fileDaEliminare = null) {

        if ($fileDaEliminare == "tutti") {

            echo 'CASE 1: ', $fileDaEliminare, "<br>";
            $percorso = UPLOADFOLDER;
            echo '$percorso: ', $percorso, "<br><br>";
        }
        else {

            echo 'CASE 2: ', $fileDaEliminare, "<br>";
            $percorso = APPROOT . DS . UPLOADFOLDER . DS . $this->idIncarico;
            echo '$percorso: ', $percorso, "<br><br>";
        }
    }
}

$fileDaEliminare = 'test123';
$allegato = new MyClass();
$allegato->delete('tutti');             // test CASE 1
$allegato->delete($fileDaEliminare);    // test CASE 2
?>
```

***P.S.*** The comments on your original question have valid points your error suggests the issue is with **UPLOADFOLDER** constant, so look into that where it is defined. Notice in my example code above that I have defined that same constant at the top.

Comment: Thank you! I did 2 stupid mistakes: didn't see that config file wasn't included and wrote in here withour thinking before ;-)